# How to repeat a capturing group?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex for validating an IP address.

While this works:

```
String reg = "((0|1)?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])";
public String pattern = reg + "." + reg + "." + reg + "." + reg;
```

This doesn't seem to work and I don't understand what is wrong.

```
String pattern = "((0|1)?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]\\.){3}((0|1)?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])";
```

Please explain what am I missing.

Comment: keep in mind that "." means "match anything"

if you want to match the "." in an ip address you would use "\."

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew :   The first one works. Second one doesn't. I want to write the repeated version of it. Is there something wrong with {3}.

Comment: @DustinRyan-Roepsch Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not grouping correctly: the dot `\\.` is part of the `25[0-5]` production, so it wouldn't be matched in the middle of your three-part group unless the address consists exclusively of `25x` components.

Your first regex is free from this problem because dots are added outside the grouping parentheses. However, the dots are not escaped, meaning that the expression would match some incorrect strings along with the correct ones (e.g. `123a210b132c210`)

Adding parentheses around your digit productions fixes this problem:

```
(((0|1)?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}((0|1)?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])
//^                             ^
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/qZ1lB7/1)

Comment: Wow!! Worked. Thanks! and I understood it too!